# What is the name and purpose of this Instrumentation / Mechanical fitting

Tags: sensors, mechanical, electrical, instrumentation

The component I am interested in is the blue "head" in the attached image. I call it the sensor head but will like to know if it has a specific industry name
[image: enter image desciption here]

Comment: Waterproof connection housing?

Comment: Several possibilities without more information.

Answer (score 3):

I'd call the blue part the `transmitter housing`.
This usually contains electronics for sensor signal conversion, which converts the sensor (or probe) low level signal to a standard 4-20 mA signal.

The sensor (probe) is the metallic cylinder. And the `sensor head` (containing the sensing element, membrane/coil) is usually located at the end surface of the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The part in your image is a Level Transmitter, https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32711941471.html

The silver bit is the transducer, and the blue bit is the transmitter/